# Hartshorne Prop. II.2.2 (b) (covering by finite number of $D(h_i)$)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question concerns a minor point in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, the proof of Proposition II.2.2 (c), specifically, the part that I have a problem with can be found right at the top of page 72:

> Next we observe that $D(f)$ can be covered by a finite number of the $D(h_i)$. Indeed, $D(f) \subseteq \bigcup D(h_i)$ if and only if $V((f)) \supseteq \bigcap V((h_i)) = V ( \sum (h_i))$. By (2.1c) again, this is equivalent to saying $f \in \sqrt{\sum (h_i)}$, or $f^n \in \sum (h_i)$ for some $n$. This means that $f^n$ can be expresed as a *finite* sum $f^n = \sum b_i h_i$, $b_i \in A$.

My problem is entirely that last sentence. I cannot for the life of my figure out why $f^n$ necessarily **must** be expressible as a finite sum.

Comment: Is your confusion beyond the fact that there are finitely many affine opens in the cover, hence finitely many generators of the ideal $\sum (h_i)$?

Comment: No, I'd say, if you could help me by convincing me that there are finitely many affine opens, and why that implies that "hence", I would be perfectly satisfied! :)

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed a word and got the implications mixed up. But I think this just follows from definitions. The ideal in $R$ on any set of generators, infinite or not, is the set of finite $R$-linear combinations of those generators. The point of this paragraph is to show that $D(f)$ being covered by a set of distinguished opens is equivalent to a certain ring-theoretic statement that has to be finite by definition, allowing us to select a finite subcover.

Comment: "The ideal in  on any set of generators, infinite or not, is the set of finite -linear combinations of those generators." The definition of an ideal itself *demands* that it be a *finite* linear combination? I actually didn't know that! If that's the case, then it's straightforward and simple from there! Thanks for filling this gap in my knowledge, mate! :)

Comment: @TabesBridges that looks like a correct answer to me! Would you care to post it as an answer?

Comment: @KReiser will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a (commutative) ring $R$. If we fix a subset $S \subset R$ (finite or otherwise), the ideal generated by $S$ is the direct sum
$$
\bigoplus_{s\in S} Rs,
$$

i.e. the set of *finite* $R$-linear combinations of those generators. The point of this paragraph in Hartshorne is to show that $D(f)$ being covered by a set of distinguished opens is equivalent to a certain ring-theoretic statement that has to be finite by definition, thereby allowing us to select a finite subcover.

Incidentally, after plugging in definitions this statement is basically the same as "every affine scheme is quasicompact," which is one of the reasons the topological definition of compactness is not the "right" definition in AG: it just applies to too many objects, in particular affine spaces (this is especially amusing given that the dual concept, Hausdorffness, is "wrong for the dual reason": it applies to basically nothing).